# Dropping rows where percentage of total in group is below threshold

Tags: python, pandas

In this dataframe:

```
        City Province  Sales
0    Toronto       ON     13
1   Montreal       QC      6
2  Vancouver       BC     16
3    Calgary       AL      8
4   Edmonton       AL      4
5   Winnipeg       MN      3
6    Windsor       ON      1
```

I want to drop the rows where the % of Sales in a province is < 15% of total. e.g. in this case, the resulting dataframe will be:

```
        City Province  Sales
0    Toronto       ON     13
1  Vancouver       BC     16
2    Calgary       AL      8
3   Edmonton       AL      4
4    Windsor       ON      1
```

Comment: no it does not, that question is about a simple condition which is specific to row. My question is about a condition that applies to a group

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`GroupBy.transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.GroupBy.transform.html) with `sum`,
divide by [`Series.div`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.div.html) total and last filter by [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df.groupby('Province')['Sales'].transform('sum').div(df['Sales'].sum()) > 0.15]
print (df)
        City Province  Sales
0    Toronto       ON     13
2  Vancouver       BC     16
3    Calgary       AL      8
4   Edmonton       AL      4
6    Windsor       ON      1
```

Answer (score 1):

```
tot=df.Sales.sum()#Find sum of column
df[df.groupby(['City','Province'])['Sales'].transform(lambda x: (x.div(tot)*100)<15)]#calculate percentage filter as per condition
```

Comment: I believe the groupby should only be by province, but yes, `transform` is the way to go

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this is the most direct route, but this gives the output as shown in the OP's question:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({
    'City': ['Toronto', 'Montreal', 'Vancouver', 'Calgary', 'Edmonton', 'Winnipeg', 'Windsor'],
    'Province': ['ON', 'QC', 'BC', 'AB', 'AB', 'MN', 'ON'],
    'Sales': [13,6,16,8,4,3,1]
})

prov_pct = df.groupby('Province')['Sales'].sum() / df['Sales'].sum()
prov_keep = prov_pct[prov_pct > 0.15].index
df[df['Province'].isin(prov_keep)]

Output:

    City   Province Sales
0   Toronto     ON  13
2   Vancouver   BC  16
3   Calgary     AB  8
4   Edmonton    AB  4
6   Windsor     ON  1
```

Whereas @wwnde 's answer outputs as:

```
df[df.groupby('Province')['Sales'].transform(lambda x: (x / tot*100) > 15)]  #calculate percentage filter as per condition

    City    Province    Sales
0   Toronto       ON    13
2   Vancouver     BC    16
3   Calgary       AB    8
```